# KeyCloak getProvider() return null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null, keycloak

my KeycloakSmsAuthenticatorUtil class has a getMessage(AuthenticationFlowContext context, String key) method that uses the themeProvider to get the theme, but the keycloakSession.getProvider() always returns null.

```
public class KeycloakSmsAuthenticatorUtil {

private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(KeycloakSmsAuthenticatorUtil.class);

...

public static String getMessage(AuthenticationFlowContext context, String key) {
    String result = null;

    try {
        ThemeProvider themeProvider = context.getSession().getProvider(ThemeProvider.class, "extending");
    
    if (themeProvider == null) {
            logger.warn("THEME PROVIDER IS NULL");
        }
     
        Theme currentTheme = themeProvider.getTheme(context.getRealm().getLoginTheme(), Theme.Type.LOGIN);
        Locale locale = context.getSession().getContext().resolveLocale(context.getUser());
        result = currentTheme.getMessages(locale).getProperty(key);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.warn(key + "not found in messages");
    }

    return result;
}
```

Themeprovider is null, so the program crashes on the next line when the currentTheme is received.

```
.[0m.[33m16:43:40,550 WARN  [six.six.keycloak.authenticator.KeycloakSmsAuthenticatorUtil] (default task-2) THEME PROVIDER IS NULL
.[0m.[33m16:43:40,551 WARN  [org.keycloak.services] (default task-2) KC-SERVICES0013: Failed authentication: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at deployment.keycloak-sms-authenticator-sns-test.jar//six.six.keycloak.authenticator.KeycloakSmsAuthenticatorUtil.getMessage(KeycloakSmsAuthenticatorUtil.java:173)
```

how can i get a non nullable themeProvider?
the error is in the ThemeProvider, not in the context or keycloakSession.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced ThemeProvider with ThemeManager, it helped.

```
public static String getMessage(AuthenticationFlowContext context, String key) {
        String result = null;
        try {
            KeycloakSession keycloakSession = context.getSession();

            RealmModel realmModel = context.getRealm();

            String loginTheme = realmModel.getLoginTheme();

            ThemeManager themeManager = keycloakSession.theme();

            Theme currentTheme = themeManager.getTheme(loginTheme, Theme.Type.LOGIN);

            Locale locale = 
 context.getSession().getContext().resolveLocale(context.getUser());
            result = currentTheme.getMessages(locale).getProperty(key);
          
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.warn(key + "not found in messages");
        }

        return result;
    }
```